# Interpolating data source name in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, interpolation, terraform

Am trying to write a terraform module for attaching bucket policy to a AWS S3 bucket. Here is the code:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "make_objects_public" {
  # if policy_name == <this-policy-name>, then generate policy
  count = "${var.policy_name == "make_objects_public" ? 1 : 0}"

  statement {
    ...
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_policy" {
  # if policy_name != "", then add the generated policy
  count = "${var.policy_name != "" ? 1 : 0}"

  bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.<policy-name-goes-here>.json}"
}
```

I want to interpolate the `policy_name` variable while fetching the policy generated by `aws_iam_policy_document`. I tried few things but sadly they didn't work. Is this possible in terraform ?

I tried out these hacks:

```
policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document."${var.policy_name}".json}"

policy = "${"${format("%s", "data.aws_iam_policy_document.${var.policy_name}.json")}"}"

policy = "${format("%s", "$${data.aws_iam_policy_document.${var.policy_name}.json}")}"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic resource names are not supported because Terraform must construct the dependency graph before it begins dealing with interpolations, and thus these relationships must be explicit.

A recommended approach for this sort of setup is to break the system down into small modules, which can then be used together by a calling module to produce the desired result without duplicating all of the details.

In this particular situation, you could for example split each policy out into its own re-usable module, and then write one more re-usable module that creates an S3 bucket and associates a given policy with it. Then a calling configuration may selectively instantiate one policy module appropriate to its needs along with the general S3 bucket module, to create the desired result:

```
module "policy" {
  # policy-specific module; only contains the policy data source
  source = "../policies/make_objects_public"

  # (any other arguments the policy needs...)
}

module "s3_bucket" {
  # S3 bucket module creates a bucket and attaches a policy to it
  source = "../s3_bucket" # general resource for S3 buckets with attached policies

  name   = "example"
  policy = "${module.policy.policy_json}" # an output from the policy module above
}
```

As well as avoiding the need for dynamic resource selection, this also increases flexibility by decoupling policy generation from the S3 bucket creation, and in principle allowing a calling module with *unusual* needs to skip instantiating a policy module altogether and just use `aws_iam_policy_document` directly.

The above pattern is somewhat analogous to [the *dependency injection* technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), where the system is split into small components (modules, in this case) and then the root config "wires up" these components in a manner appropriate for a specific use-case. This approach has very similar advantages and disadvantages as the general technique.

Comment: Good analogy with dependency injection technique. For anyone who is looking for more details this question is also tracked in [GitHub issues](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15859).

Comment: Could you explain why policy = "${var.environment == "foo" ? data.aws_iam_policy_document.foo.json : data.aws_iam_policy_document.bar.json}" seems to work?

Comment: In a situation where a conditional refers to different resources in each of its expressions, the dependency graph conservatively includes both of them: the referring resource would depend on both `data.aws_iam_policy_document.foo` _and_ `data.aws_iam_policy_document.bar`.